# ATT Assembly (arithmetic and logical operations)

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-shift, att

```
// Code I'll be working with
int shift_left2_rightn(int x, int n)
{
    x <<= 2;
    x >>= n;
    return x;
}
```

Question 1. Left shift = `SAL` and `SHL`. My book says they have the same effect. Then why are there two shift operations?

For example:

```
movl    8(%ebp), %eax    //Get x
_______                  //x <<= 2
```

My book gives an answer of

```
sall    $2, %eax
```

would

```
shll    $2, %eax
```

also been the correct answer?

Question 2:

In layman's terms what is the difference between `SHR` and `SAR`? My book says one is a logical shift (fills with zeroes) and other is arithmetic shift (fills with copies of the sign bit).

Fills what with 0's/sign bits?

For example:

How would I know which one to use with the following assembly instructions?

```
movl   12(%ebp), %ecx   //Get n
______                  //x >>=n
```

Back of the book has the answer

```
sarl   %cl, %eax
```

Please explain to me what would happen if we used `shrl`.

Thanks for your help with understanding this!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sal` and `shl` are synonymous, they have identical opcodes.

As `sar` does signed division by 2 rounding numbers towards negative infinity (-Inf), and `shr` does unsigned division by 2, probably engineers at Intel have decided to incorporate also both `sal` and `shl` even if they are synonymous.

Here's an example what `shr` and `sar` do:

```
mov al,0b10001000 ; 0b10001000 = 136d = -120d (2's complement)

shr al,1          ; 0b01000100 =  68d =   68d (2's complement)

mov al,0b10001000 ; 0b10001000 = 136d = -120d (2's complement)

sar al,1          ; 0b11000100 = 196d =  -60d (2's complement)
```

So `shr` fills with zeroes, and `sar` fills with the sign bit.

`shr` is for unsigned divisions or bit shifts in general, and `sar` for signed divisions.

Comment: Thanks alot for the examples and explanation

Comment: There are actually two different opcodes for `sal` and `shl`, but so far their behavior has been identical, although it looks like Intel wants to deprecate one of the two if you judge by their documentation.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Which ones? In [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.html) I am able to find only the same encodings for both `sal` and `shl`: (with/without `REX`) `DO /4`, `D2 /4`, `C0 /4 ib`, `D1 /4`, `D3 /4`, `C1 /4 ib`. Also, if I assemble eg. `sal al,1` with NASM, resulting in `D0 E0`, ndisasm disassembles it as `shl al,1`.

Comment: `/6` is the other of the two.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't two different operations, just two names for the same instruction.

If you shift right, there is a difference between signed (SAR) and unsigned values (SHR), so one operation sign extends and the other does not.

When shifting left there is no difference, but it still has two names (SAL and SHL) just for the symmetry with the right shifts. They both map to the same machine code.

Comment: There are actually two different opcodes for `sal` and `shl`, but so far their behavior has been identical, although it looks like Intel wants to deprecate one of the two if you judge by their documentation.